# Swing. Adapter/Listener vs Databinding

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

I need to build an application. My data changes when user submits something. I don't need to dynamically update the GUI elements to reflect updated data.
However, i am interested in learning better ways if there are any. I stumbled across data binding. None of the books (understandably,since nothing has changed) on swing cover data binding. Every book involves Adapters/Listeners.
So, i'd like to know what Data binding offers and is it better approach than Adapter/Listener approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more i look at it, the more i feel winforms is better alternative. [http://www.amazon.com/Data-Binding-Windows-Forms-2-0/dp/032126892X/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032126892X)